# Pythonic way to initialise function parameters

Tags: python, function, coding-style

Which is more pythonic?

A

```
def my_function(arg, p=0):
    while arg:
        # do something
         value = arg.pop()
        # save value with a name which uses p for indexing
    p+=1
```

or B

```
def my_function(arg):
    p = 0
    while arg:
        # do something
        value = arg.pop()
        # save value with a name which uses p for indexing
    p+=1
```

A part of me think its silly to include p as an argument to the function incase someone sets it to a weird a value. But at the same time I don't like having p=0 clutter up a function which is already very complicated.

Comment: Maybe not relevent to your question but "which is already very complicated" is a red flag if you want to do things in the pythonic way as your question suggests.

Comment: Some more detail would be useful. Looking at this code, it's not clear that `p` needs to be initialized to 0 at all before the loop runs; you could just initialize it to 1 after the loop.

Comment: If you're supposed to be indexing the items in `arg`, you can do `for p, value in enumerate(arg)`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't clutter up function parameters with locals. If it is not a parameter the caller should use, don't add it to your function signature.

In other words, you don't want anyone using `help(my_function)` and be surprised at what `p` might be for.

---

This isn't a hard and fast rule, of course; some critical-path functions can be made faster by using locals, so sometimes you'll see something like:

```
some_global = expensive_function()

def foo(bar, baz, _some_local=some_global):
    # code using _some_local instead of some_global
```

to make use of faster local name lookups. The `_` at the start of the argument then tells you that the name is really an internal implementation detail you should not rely on.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if `p` always has to start at `0` or not. If it does, then definitely go with option B. Don't give users an opportunity to mess with your code if it's not necessary.